# Possible to curve one part of a straight graph at one place only?

Tags: excel

I have a graph in the form of straight lines in my excel sheet (see image)

I want make the line between "TDP 130 ft" and "200 m" **curved downwards**, (ie towards the x-axis) but just that part, the other parts of the graph should remain straight lines. Is this even possible? It is not important what values the curved part has since the graph is mostly for illustration purpose.

I have attached the data from which the graph is created.

[image: Current Graph]
[image: Data]

EDIT: New image with extra line.

[image: New image with extra line added]

Comment: make two separate lines in the graph that look the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Luuklag allready mentioned in his comment, you should use two different datasets, like illustrated below:

[image]

Both the same graphtypes, all I did was setting the second dataset to curviture line.

**EDIT**

To create the curviture, you have to select that line (click in graph on that line) and tick the box that says to use the curviture line on the right settings:

[image]

I hope it's clear now! Also note I left a gap in the data with straight lines that is filled with the curved line data. Otherwise you will end up having two lines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have added a second graph, see my original post for updated image. I cannot figure out how to make it curved though :-S